# Attach worker to CEX.IO account

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration, cex.io, ghash.io

I have been able to set up basic mining using minerd, and it is happily mining away on GHash.IO. However, it doesn't seem to be attached to my CEX.IO account, even though I am mining with these arguments:

```
minerd --url stratum+tcp://uk1.ghash.io:3333 --threads 2 --userpass [myusername].worker1:
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: The above was mining with my account after all. A refresh rate of 1/day lead me to believe otherwise. Sorry to waste everyone's time!

Comment: Why do you have a `:` on the end?

Comment: The colon separates the username and the password. As a password isn't required for my pool, the left side is left empty.

Answer (score -1):

this work
./minerd --url=stratum+tcp://uk1.ghash.io:3333 -u username.workername -p xxx